# rails unable to index a foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a two separate migration files:

```
class CreateLeadProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :lead_profiles do |t|
      t.belongs_to :Contact

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :lead_profiles, :contact_id
  end
end
```

and:

```
class CreateClientProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :client_profiles do |t|
      t.belongs_to :Contact
      t.belongs_to :LeadProfile

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :client_profiles, :contact_id
    add_index :client_profiles, :lead_profile_id
  end
end
```

when running rake db:migrate, I get the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Key column 'lead_profile_id' doesn't exist in table: CREATE  INDEX `index_client_profiles_on_lead_profile_id`  ON `client_profiles` (`lead_profile_id`)
```

client_profile belongs_to lead_profile, and so should have a lead_profile_id. And I want that foreign key to be indexed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
class CreateClientProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :client_profiles do |t|
      t.belongs_to :contact
      t.belongs_to :lead_profile

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :client_profiles, :contact_id
    add_index :client_profiles, :lead_profile_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes that did end up working. Rails 4 no longer supports the other syntax?